# Symfony2 - Set different log files using Monolog.

Tags: php, symfony, monolog

In config.yml can I have something like?

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        hand1:
            type: stream
            path: "%kernel.root_dir%/logs/symfony1.log"
            level: info
        hand2:
            type: stream
            path: "%kernel.root_dir%/logs/symfony2.log"
            action_level: info
```

And how can I select in each moment or in each controller, what handler or in what file can I write the logs?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use channels  (Monolog 2.4+)

In config.yml :

```
monolog:
    channels: [channel1, channel2]
    handlers:
        main:
            type:  stream
            path:  %kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log
            level: debug
        channel1:
            type: stream
            path:  %kernel.logs_dir%/channel1.log
            channels: [channel1]
```

In controller :

```
$this->get('monolog.logger.channel1')->info("...");
```